# How to get a json file into a text variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, variables

I am new using a json file and i wanna put the file into a text variable in javascript to run a function not in a object....
I have been trying something like this.. but nothing...

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "json/test.json", function() {
                  console.log( "success" );
                })

alert (getDepth(jqxhr));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is retrieve the contents of the JSON file within your success callback -

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "json/test.json", function(jsonData) { 
  console.log( jsonData );
})
```

Note that the resulting variable (`jsonData`) does not in fact contain text - it contains a JavaScript object.

Comment: This is misleading. It implies that `receivedData` will be available for a statement that could be added to line 5.

Comment: I wan to get something like this from the file, the data in a variable. ' var input = {
    "name": "positive",
    "children": [{
        "name": "product service",
        "children": [{
            "name": "price",
            "children": [{
                "name": "cost",
                "size": 8
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "quality",
            "children": [{
                "name": "messaging",
                "size": 4
            }]
        }]
    }]
}'